# How to create a cloud server based website?

Tags: domains, server, windows, cloud-hosting, dreamweaver

i have bought a domain from go daddy. i have bought a cloud hosting windows 2008 server from rack space. how do i link my domain to my host server and how do i utilize Dreamweaver/fireworks to create the website on the server? any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Point the domain to your host's nameservers, add the domain to your hosting account and google the rest.